# How to return to stop multiple levels up

Tags: python, function

I want to be able to return to stop the parent function inside a function like this:

```py
def FunctionBeingRan():
    #Running Script
    def stop():
        return #return to stop the parent function
    
FunctionBeingRan().stop
```

Anyone know how to do this

Comment: What do you expect `FunctionBeingRan().stop` to do?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I want it to stop the FunctionBeingRan function, I will be calling FunctionBeingRan().stop in another script, so I can loop the FunctionBeingRan, until I stop it

Comment: Okay, that's something totally different from what I understood before. Do you use multithreading?

Comment: You want to notify the function that is doing some work in a loop, so that it can stop its work. This is likely to be dealt with `Event` primitive in the asyncio module, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Alright, thanks

Comment: Note that you must use multithreading. Otherwise there will only be one function running at a time. Introducing multithreading into your program without knowing what it does may result in effects that you don't want. Even with an `Event`, the function will need to check that event continuously. It will still not stop long running method calls in libraries.

Answer (score -1):

you can return some number represent stop such as -1 and add a check statement to it .

```
def FunctionBeingRan():
    #Running Script
    def stop():
        return #return to stop the parent function
    
    if stop() == -1:
        return
```

as python doesn't have `goto` statement, but there do have some nice packages that implement it

```
from goto import with_goto

@with_goto
def fun1(start, stop):
    label .begin
    # your code here
    def stop():
       # stop logical here
       goto .end
    # your remaining code here
    label .end
    return result
```

but it is dangerous for making code hard to read.
The best way is refact your logic.